# Check Constraint SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 columns in a table -

[SendDate] and [PayDate]

I am trying to implement a constraint that will check that - the product cannot be paid for if it has not been sent out.

Basically in simpler words IF SendDate is NULL then PayDate cannot containt a value or something like
                           IF SendDate is NULL then if user types in something to PayDate, an error will rise

I am not sure how to go on about it.

Any suggestions much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Check` constraint like this

```
CHECK( [PayDate] IS NULL OR ([PayDate] IS NOT NULL AND [SendDate] IS NOT NULL))
```

**Sample**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Payment
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [SendDate] DATE NULL,
    [PayDate] DATE NULL,
    CONSTRAINT CHK_PayDate CHECK( [PayDate] IS NULL OR ([PayDate] IS NOT NULL AND [SendDate] IS NOT NULL))
)

-- All Fine
INSERT INTO dbo.Payment([SendDate],[PayDate]) VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO dbo.Payment([SendDate],[PayDate]) VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.Payment([SendDate],[PayDate]) VALUES(NULL,NULL);

--Raises Error
INSERT INTO dbo.Payment([SendDate],[PayDate]) VALUES(NULL,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```